# Odoo 10 Scheduled Actions Not Working odoo.service.server: WorkerCron

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have Odoo 10 working since last 4 years. The Scheduled actions have been working fine until 7th May 2021.

Server Specs :
CPU - 4
Ram 16 GB
Ubuntu

The database name is : **kwspl**

In the server log, I find the following lines :

```
 File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/bus/controllers/main.py", line 35, in poll
    raise Exception("bus.Bus unavailable")
Exception: bus.Bus unavailable
2021-05-24 15:50:54,391 2376 INFO kwspl werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2021 15:50:54] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
**2021-05-24 15:50:56,701 2381 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2381) polling for jobs
2021-05-24 15:50:56,702 2381 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2381) 'kwspl' time:0.001s mem: 233352k -> 233352k (diff: 0k)
2021-05-24 15:51:03,660 2382 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2382) polling for jobs
2021-05-24 15:51:03,662 2382 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2382) 'kwspl' time:0.002s mem: 233352k -> 233352k (diff: 0k)**
2021-05-24 15:51:04,530 2379 DEBUG kwspl odoo.modules.registry: Multiprocess signaling check: [Registry - 614 -> 614] [Cache - 57570 -> 57570]
2021-05-24 15:51:04,532 2379 ERROR kwspl odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
```

The odoo.conf is as below :

```
[options]
addons_path = /opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons,/opt/odoo/custom/addons
admin_passwd = ******
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = /opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo
#db_filter = kwspl
db_host = False
db_maxconn = 64
#db_name = False
db_name = 'kwspl'
db_password = False
db_port = False
db_template = template1
db_user = odoo
dbfilter = ^kwspl$
demo = {}
email_from = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
import_partial =
limit_memory_hard = 4684354560
limit_memory_soft = 4147483648
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 420
limit_time_real = 180
limit_time_real_cron = -1
list_db = False
log_db = False
log_db_level = warning
#log_handler = :INFO
log_level = debug
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
logrotate = False
longpolling_port = 8072
max_cron_threads = 2
osv_memory_age_limit = 1.0
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = None
pidfile = None
proxy_mode = True
reportgz = False
server_wide_modules = web,web_kanban
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_commit = False
test_enable = False
test_file = False
test_report_directory = False
translate_modules = ['all']
unaccent = False
without_demo = False
workers = 4
xmlrpc = True
#xmlrpc_interface =
xmlrpc_port = 8069
```

If I change the following paramenters in odoo.conf

```
db_name = False 
dbfilter = ^%d$
```

The following lines are seen in the log:

```
    raise Exception("bus.Bus unavailable")
Exception: bus.Bus unavailable
2021-05-24 15:59:58,457 2574 INFO kwspl werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2021 15:59:58] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-05-24 16:00:03,261 2576 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2576) polling for jobs
2021-05-24 16:00:03,316 2576 DEBUG ? odoo.tools.translate: translation went wrong for "'Selecting the "Warning" option will notify user with the message, Selecting "Blocking Message" will throw an exception with the message and block the flow. The Message has to be written in the next field.'", skipped
2021-05-24 16:00:03,376 2576 WARNING ? odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Skipping database kwspl because of modules to install/upgrade/remove.
2021-05-24 16:00:03,377 2576 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'dbname=kwspl user=odoo'
2021-05-24 16:00:03,377 2576 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2576) kwspl time:0.109s mem: 220928k -> 227084k (diff: 6156k)
2021-05-24 16:00:03,377 2576 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2576) polling for jobs
2021-05-24 16:00:03,388 2576 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to "dbname=\\'kwspl\\' user=odoo"
2021-05-24 16:00:03,388 2576 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2576) 'kwspl' time:0.006s mem: 227084k -> 227084k (diff: 0k)
2021-05-24 16:00:04,190 2577 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2577) polling for jobs
2021-05-24 16:00:04,244 2577 DEBUG ? odoo.tools.translate: translation went wrong for "'Selecting the "Warning" option will notify user with the message, Selecting "Blocking Message" will throw an exception with the message and block the flow. The Message has to be written in the next field.'", skipped
2021-05-24 16:00:04,264 2577 WARNING ? odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Skipping database kwspl because of modules to install/upgrade/remove.
2021-05-24 16:00:04,264 2577 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to 'dbname=kwspl user=odoo'
2021-05-24 16:00:04,264 2577 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2577) kwspl time:0.068s mem: 220928k -> 227172k (diff: 6244k)
2021-05-24 16:00:04,265 2577 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2577) polling for jobs
2021-05-24 16:00:04,274 2577 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: ConnectionPool(used=0/count=0/max=64): Closed 1 connections to "dbname=\\'kwspl\\' user=odoo"
2021-05-24 16:00:04,275 2577 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: WorkerCron (2577) 'kwspl' time:0.006s mem: 227172k -> 227172k (diff: 0k)
2021-05-24 16:00:05,377 2571 DEBUG kwspl odoo.modules.registry: Multiprocess signaling check: [Registry - 614 -> 614] [Cache - 57570 -> 57570]
```

The Scheduled Actions are no longer running while the automated Tasks are working normally.

Is this problem causing this ? -> `Skipping database kwspl because of modules to install/upgrade/remove.`

If this is the issue, do I check which module is the culprit?

Any Guesses?

Answer (score 1):

On further investigation, I found that there was an error message in logs :

```
crm_rma_lot_mass_return: module not found
```

I tried to find this module in the current directories but could not find.
So I created an Odoo scaffolding with the same name and uploaded it on the server in one of the include directories mentioned in odoo-server.conf

This solved the problem. Odoo is now executing the Scheduled Actions.

If some faced a similar problem, I would be happy to help.